# "von den/der zwei reichen Leuten": genitive or dative?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, declension

In nthuleen, it is given that

> Die kleinen Kinder von den zwei reichen Leuten gehen in diese teure Schule

However, shouldn't "von den zwei reichen Leuten" be like "von der zwei reichen Leuten"?
Namely, shouldn't "von den/der zwei reichen Leuten" be in a genitive case since it is indicating possesion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Die kleinen Kinder *von den zwei reichen Leuten* gehen in diese teure Schule.

The part in italics must not be in genitive case, because the preposition [*von*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/von) always demands the dative case. You could, however, express it in genitive case by dropping the preposition:

> Die kleinen Kinder *der zwei reichen Leute* gehen in diese teure Schule.

Comment: In general, possession is shown by **either** genitive or *von*, **but not both**. The two are similar but not always interchangeable, there are even cases where you'd use *von* in German but "'s" in English: *Wir hören die Mondscheinsonate von Beethovan.* – "We're listening to Beethovan's Moonlight Sonata."

Answer (score 2):

Die Präposition "von" erfordert den Dativ. Verzichtet man auf "von", kann man den Besitz durch Genitiv ausdrücken.

von + Dativ:

> Die Kinder von reichen Leuten gehen auf die Schule

Genitiv:

> Die Kinder reicher Leute gehen auf die Schule